# BGE: hold at last frame

Tags: python

I hope i can make myself clear:

I'm making a 3th person adventure game, and thinks start to work just fine, but I came across a problem and now i'm stuck.

**Situation:**
*It is an platform game, so not an action game. The characte does have 1 weapon tough (A blowpipe). When the player is in possession of the blowpipe, he can aim/zoom by pressing right mouse button* >> all of this works!

**Problem:** While zooming, the character puts the blowpipe against his mouth (to make it look more real). The action itself works, but it keeps on looping the animation. Is there a way to hold it on the last frame??

here is my code:

```
def main():

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard
mouse = bge.logic.mouse

zKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.ZKEY]
sKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.SKEY]
dKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.DKEY]
qKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.QKEY]
lefM = mouse.events[bge.events.LEFTMOUSE] == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED
rigM = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == mouse.events[bge.events.RIGHTMOUSE]


spaceKey = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED == keyboard.events[bge.events.SPACEKEY]

# Met de juiste toetsen moet het Personage de juiste animaties spelen
if zKey:
    own.playAction('metarigAction',31,52,layer=0, blendin=0, play_mode=bge.logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_LOOP)
elif sKey:
    own.playAction('metarigAction',52,31,layer=0, blendin=0, play_mode=bge.logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_LOOP)
elif lefM:
    own.playAction('metarigAction',79,100,layer=1, blendin=2, play_mode=bge.logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_PLAY)
elif rigM:
    own.playAction('metarigAction',135,145,layer=2, blendin=2, play_mode=bge.logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_PLAY)
#het personage moet altijd ademen wanneer niets anders is ingedrukt
else:
    own.playAction('metarigAction',5,21,layer=0, blendin=2, play_mode=bge.logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_PING_PONG)           
main()
```

this is the line for the aiming animation:

```
elif rigM:
    own.playAction('metarigAction',135,145,layer=2, blendin=2, play_mode=bge.logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_PLAY)
```

**THANKS IN ADVANCE!**
Hope I made myself clear!

G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `rigM` will be constantly true when the right mouse button is held down. This means the action will keep playing. Try changing `bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE`  to `bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED` in your definition for `rigM`.

Give the breathing animation a lower priority by setting the `priority` argument on your `playaction` call to a high number. See the [Game Types API Reference](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_60a_release/bge.types.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.playAction) for details. If you don't want other actions to play while the right mouse button is held down then change your logic to not play the action when `rigM` is true.

Comment: thx for the answer, but i tried that already.. the problem is that it needs to be aiming as long as the mouse-button is pressed.. When i put just activated, it plays the animation one time...

I think that is because when he played the animation once, it goes back to the 'breathing' animation:


`'#When no button is pressed the character ahs to breath
else:
    own.playAction('metarigAction',5,21,layer=0, blendin=2, play_mode=bge.logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_PING_PONG)           
main()'`.

Comment: Okay, when i remove the statement that it has to play the 'breathing animation', it works, but the the problem is that the rest of the animations don't stop.

for example:
When i press z, the 'walking animation' loops as long as the key is pressed. When nothing is pressed, the character stops walking, the animation loop stops and the animation for breathing starts. 

When i leave the statement for 'breathing' out of the code and change rigM to JUST_ACTIVATED, it works the way i want to, but all the other animations don't stop playing when I stop pressing the button...

Comment: Thing is, if i can stop the breathing animation, while the right-mouse-button is pressed, it is fixed, but it really doesn't work the regular ways...